# Drawing app for android using libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new to the libGdx framework but i have been developing android apps for couple months now. The problem that i'm facing is that i'm unable to get a way to make an app where i can draw the items as user make using gestures. 
    I have searched a lot but couldn't find a work around to do the following using libgdx framework.

Basically what my plan is:

1. I will check if the user is dragging "isdragging()", if yes i want to use either "DDA algorithm" to create the lines as per the inputs received from the "dragstart()" from the "Gesturedetection" interface but i'm not receiving any data from the methods.
2. based on the user's action the pixmap will be rendered.

Any sort of help will be helpful.

Comment: i had to implement same kind of feature for a game i made 3 years ago. to solve this problem. i put everything from my dekstop and main project to android project and then for that special feature of drawing board i used native android and switched from game activity to drawing activity and then after drawing switched back to game activity. then there was not much of scene 2d and i was using 0.9.6 i think with recent development there should be a solution if not then u can go for this lenghty and stupid solution.

Comment: What are your plans for implementing eraser?. just to use eraser i did that android switching thing

Comment: Can you please be bit specific in terms of code?no i just want to have a drawing app and store those drawings

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using Scene2D you can easily use DragListener binded with your stage to get (x,y) pointer position whenewer user will touch down the stage and move his pointer

```
stage.addListener( 
    new DragListener()
    {
        public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
        {
            Vector2 v = new Vector2(x, y);
            positionArray.add(v); //positionArray is Array<Vector2> type in this example
        }
    }
);
```

then you can just remember the position in an Array for example (Array seems to be nice choose) and in the *render* part you can use **ShapeRenderer** or some another tool to render these points. Because you have all points remembered you can easily remove them when using "rubber".

Regards,
Michał

Comment: Sorry I made one mistake - x and y are delta od position you habe started dragging from - you can remember in a variable start point (there's method dragStart - looks exactly like drag but triggering once) and then add to array start point + (x,y) instead od just (x,y)

Comment: but it won't work as the following gives me only a black screen nothing else